# MYSQL How to grant all privileges to user only to the databases which he created?

Tags: mysql, shell, mariadb, privileges

im creating a few users:
user1
user2
user3
i want to give them ALL PRIVILEGES to the bases(creating/removing) inside their account
i want them to see and affect databases only inside their account... 
how should i do this with shell ?

Comment: Are you asking how to grant the privileges in the database, or are you asking how to write a shell script that iterates over the users?

Comment: For the first part, you should ask in [dba.se].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you allow users to run `CREATE DATABASE ...`?

Don't allow a user to run that SQL.  Instead, provide a `STORED PROCEDURE` to create the database for him and provide permissions to him.  The trick is to be `root` when you define the SP and use `SQL SECURITY DEFINER`.  And have `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON dbname.* TO user@...`  (with the pieces suitably filled in).